# Response from api with vueform

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How I can receive response from my API?

I'm using vueform with its endpoints, but I don't understand how to get a response from my API and use it.
I understand that you can abandon this library and do it manually using the same fetch, but I want to use this library because it is more practical and convenient.

```
<template>
  <Vueform v-bind="vueform">
  </Vueform>
</template>

<script>
import {useVueform, Vueform } from '@vueform/vueform'
import {ref} from 'vue'
export default {
  mixins: [Vueform],
  setup(props, context)
  {
    const form = useVueform(props, context)
    const vueform = ref({
      method: 'POST',
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:5002/api/user/login',
      displayErrors: true,
      resposne: {
        data: {}
      },
      schema: {
        h1: {
          type: 'static',
          tag: 'h1',
          content: 'Input Secret-code',
        },
        code: {
          type: 'text',
          placeholder: 'Code',
          size: 'lg',
        },
        submit: {
          type: 'button',
          buttonLabel: 'Submit',
          submits: true,
          align: 'right',
          size: 'lg',
        }
      },
    })
    return {
      ...form,
      vueform,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's expected that the library provides the flexibility to do this and there's no reason to discard it. In this case it's https://vueform.com/docs/handling-form-data#dynamic-endpoint . It seems it already has this feature but it's opinionated regarding the way it handles the result, so the backend needs to be adjusted ti fit it https://github.com/vueform/vueform/blob/f3248c70bcd15ad8ad8acf4fb46f870efd7c229f/src/composables/useVueform.js#L1151-L1168 , and this is not documented